# tail file - count number of lines with a given pattern

Tags: linux, ssh, tail

I need to guarantee that a specific string is appearing in an active log file,
meaning an operation is alive (feeding this count to a Trigger).

Considering I'll do this remotely, 
I can't go with 'tail -f filename' else it would follow the file indefinitely, 
thus I'm thinking about grabbing a bunch of last written lines and counting them as,

```
tail -n8 /var/log/service/service_V138/operations.log| grep \|DONE\| | wc -l
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Your `question` was the most helpful answer for my particular situation.  Thanks for asking this and sharing what you were already doing!

Comment: @jmort253, that's why stackoverflow and its siblings are so helpful.
Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can improve this a bit, by removing the pipe to `wc` and using `grep -c` instead.

```
tail -n8 /var/log/service/service_V138/operations.log | grep -c \|DONE\|
```

Comment: Thanks.
My main doubt was if there was any alternative method to follow the file for a few seconds before disconnecting, 
guaranteeing the file was being actively written, just doesn't have the given string.

Comment: tail -f -n+1 apache-tomcat-7.0.63/logs/localhost_access_log.2017-01-29.txt | grep -c lenskart is not working for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

less +F -N somelogfile.log ?pattern
simple and easy

Comment: Following the log, 
inserting a pause in the script, 
and feeding the ssh conn with a 'CTRL+C' some seconds later right?